# Как изменить цвет div через js

Tags: javascript

Есть вот такие дивы
`<html>`

```
<div class="colDiv">Color 1</div>
<div class="colDiv">Color 2</div>
<div class="colDiv">Color 3</div>
```

вот `js`

```
var colorArray = [
     document.getElementsByClassName('colDiv'),
     document.getElementsByClassName('colDiv'),
     document.getElementsByClassName('colDiv')

];
```

так получаю элементы нужно изменить цвет 2 дива

как это сделать?

Делал так:

```
myDiv.style.color = "blue";
```

пробовал так:

```
for (i = 0 ; i < colorArray.length; i++) {
    colorArray[i].style.backgroundColor = "#AA0000";
}
```

не работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` возвращает массив, поэтому просто так:

```js
var colorArray = document.getElementsByClassName('colDiv');

colorArray[1].style.backgroundColor = '#AA0000';
```

```html
<div class="colDiv">Color 1</div>
<div class="colDiv">Color 2</div>
<div class="colDiv">Color 3</div>
```

Comment: ЕЕЕ  работает!!! 10Х!!!

Answer (score 2):

Метод `getElementsByClassName` уже возвращает массив (строго говоря, [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)): нет необходимости добавлять результат в массив и тем более помещать в массив 3 раза один и тот же результат. Достаточно будет сделать так:

```js
var colorDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("colDiv");
for (var i = 0; i < colorDivs.length; i++) {
    colorDivs[i].style.backgroundColor = "#AA0000";
}
```

```html
<div class="colDiv">Color 1</div>
<div class="colDiv">Color 2</div>
<div class="colDiv">Color 3</div>
```

---

Замену цвета фона только одного div-a, соответственно, можно осуществить по конкретному индексу:

```js
var colorDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("colDiv");
colorDivs[1].style.backgroundColor = "#AA0000";
```

```html
<div class="colDiv">Color 1</div>
<div class="colDiv">Color 2</div>
<div class="colDiv">Color 3</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваш массив

```
var colorArray = [
     document.getElementsByClassName('colDiv'),
     document.getElementsByClassName('colDiv'),
     document.getElementsByClassName('colDiv')
];
```

состоит из одинаковых коллекций, полученных выборкой по имени одного и того же класса. Соответственно, код

```
colorArray[i].style.backgroundColor = "#AA0000";
```

обращается к несуществующему свойству `style`.

```js
function changeColor() {
  [...document.getElementsByClassName('colDiv')].forEach(
    item => item.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen"
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="colDiv">Color 1</div>
<div class="colDiv">Color 2</div>
<div class="colDiv">Color 3</div>
<button onclick="changeColor()">Change Color</button>
```